# My dropdown Menu does not working (react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I need help with this code, at the end production process on the page called projects, my dropdown menu does not work and I have tried many ways to fix that, nevertheless, I can't fix that. Please  I am looking forward to your help and answer.

I'm using React-Bootstrap v1.4.3 (Bootstrap 4.6)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Project from '../components/project.js';
import { projectData } from '../projectData';
import './projects.css';

export default class Projects extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projectID: '',
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const projectID = e.target;
        this.setState({ projectID: projectID })
    }

    render() {
        const selectedProject = this.state.projectID;

        return(
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 mb-5 pb-5">
                <div className="row justify-content-center pb-4">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button 
                            class="btn btn-retro dropdown-toggle textspaced textlarge" 
                            type="button" 
                            id="dropdownMenuButton" 
                            data-toggle="dropdown" 
                            aria-haspopup="true" 
                            aria-expanded="false"
                        >
                            Mission Select
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu raleway text-center" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

                            {projectData.map((project, index) => {
                                return <button class="dropdown-item" onClick={this.handleClick} id={index}>{project.title}</button>
                            })}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="pagebox shadow-lg row justify-content-center pr-0 pl-0">
                    {this.state.projectID 
                        ?   <Project 
                                title={projectData[selectedProject].title} 
                                image={projectData[selectedProject].image} 
                                description={projectData[selectedProject].description}
                                technologies={projectData[selectedProject].technologies}
                                link={projectData[selectedProject].link}
                                date={projectData[selectedProject].date_created} 
                                github={projectData[selectedProject].github}
                            />
                        :   <h2 className="col-12 text-center textyellow textspaced pt-5 mt-5">
                                Please select a mission above.
                            </h2>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define *dropdown menu does not work*...

Comment: the list menu does not appear when I'm clicking the dropdown menu button which is called "Mission Select"

Comment: I'm cloning another personal-website that is pretty cool and I'm trying to migrate my personal-website with that cloning, please kindly check this website neetmangat.com for the details, I really need your help